# How to debug a Jquery Dialog

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-ui

I have a fairly basic dialog maker for jquery that works in 2 out of 3 places.  In the 3rd instance where I try to use it, the fields in the form are disabled once the dialog is displayed.

The general concept behind the code is that the form is on a different page of the website, and for convenience, when javascript is enabled, you can click on the link, get a dialog, and perform the task "on page".  The 'rel' attribute has the selector to be used in the jquery .load method, the title of the  becomes the dialog title, the page at the 'href' loads and becomes the dialog contents.  If Javascript is off, you just get the same form, but with all the header/footer/menu stuff.

How can I figure out what is going on when the dialog displays?  Firefox becomes sluggish (right click menu is slow to pop up) and the form fields are disabled.  I'm just at a loss for how to debug this, to figure out what is going on at that point.  TAB wil select the dialog "close" button, and will select the field that already has a value in it, but that is where it ends. ESC will still close the dialog, so the keyboard is working.  I found one other person reporting a similar problem [CkEditor Bug](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5779), and they appear to have fixed it, but I don't know how they did.

Before I forget: JQuery 1.4.2  JQueryUI 1.8.2

The url looks like:

```
<a class='dialog' href='/messages/compose/fsm92766/' rel = ' #compose-message' title='Send Message to'>Send Message To</a>
```

The setup code looks like:

```
    <script lanaguage='javascript'> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.dialog').each(function() {
            var $link = $(this);
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 'auto',
                    position: 'center'
                });

            $link.click(function() {
                var $url = $link.attr('href') + $link.attr('rel');
                $dialog.html($url + "<br/>" +"<img src='http://ender.intomec.com/static/images/loading.gif'></img>");
                $dialog.load($url)
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                return false;
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

And the dialog html looks like:

```
<html>blah blah blah
<body>blah blah blah

-------------- JQuery Selector extracts this part from the page ----------------
<div id='compose-message'>
    <form action="" method="post" class="uniForm">
        <div style='display:none'>
            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='3c55a464683748b20a0e6abbcd22225d' />
        </div>      
        <fieldset class="inlineLabels">
            <div id="div_id_recipient" class="ctrlHolder ">
                <label for="id_recipient">Recipient<span>*</span></label>
                <input id="id_recipient" type="text" class="commaseparateduserinput" value="fsm92766" name="recipient" />
            </div>
            <div id="div_id_subject" class="ctrlHolder ">
                <label for="id_subject">Subject<span>*</span></label>
                <input id="id_subject" type="text" class="textinput textInput" name="subject" />
            </div>
            <div id="div_id_body" class="ctrlHolder ">
                <label for="id_body">Body<span>*</span></label>
                <textarea id="id_body" rows="12" cols="55" name="body" class="textarea"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form_block">
                <input type="submit" value="Send &raquo;"/>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
----------------------------------
blah blah blah
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would give the suggestion of Firebug by others serious thought. The reason is debugging other people's code is annoying. But, teach a man to fish, and he won't be hungry for the rest of his life. We'd be glad to provide follow up help with Firebug.

**Edit:** I misread your intention; you *were* actually asking about how to debug. Good for you. I'll leave this comment up for posterity, because it is an important lesson for many people.

Comment: I have firebug, been using it for a long time.  I'm just not sure where to start.  I can set breakpoints, but where, how can I break execution to see where it is spending its time.

I've tried the Chrome Timeline, it doesn't show it.

After some amount of time, right clicking in the Subject will cause the cursor to show up there, but all you can do is select some of the "remembered" text.  You can't type, and left click does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure, are you using **Firebug**?
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

Its a boon for debugging javascript especially if you're using firefox, they have 'lite' versions for other browsers as well.  Its the de-facto javascript debugger as far as I know.

Firebug has an add on FireQuery to enhance debugging for jQuery  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12632/

Comment: I am using firebug, what I don't know is how to see where it is hung?
JQUERY has LOTS of code and I know of no way to profile that code to see where the time is spent.

Comment: I don't think you are looking very hard. I just googled on jquery profiling and got a hit on the front page of http://getfirebug.com/javascript. Scroll down to where it says (gasp!) "Profile Javascript Performance". You go to the Console tab, click Profile, then do a page reload, and then click Profile again. You get a nice profile of everything called, # of calls, total time, yada yada.

Comment: You know I completely missed that profile button under console, even though I use it fairly often.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension for Firefox is great for debugging javascript.

Comment: Yep, provided you know where to look, it is a very useful debugger.  However, I don't think firebug has anything like the Chrome Timeline, and that isn't helping much either.